# Python or Jython for Django based application?

Tags: python, apache, glassfish, memcached, jython

We are going to start developing Django based application. It requires speed optimisation (need to serve *k+* requests/sec), *n* number of nodes with HAproxy and PostgreSQL load-balancing.

Presently we consider using

1. Python, Apache, memcached
2. Jython, Glassfish

The application should scale overtime, Python or Jython. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is Python is faster then JVM compiled Jython code? can we have any advantages of Glassfish3 over Apache?

Answer (score 4):

Which language you know better?

JVM based languages are faster than Python but any access to data(sql,nosql) is 100X slower than Python or Java.

You will have problems with the database first.

Concentrate on that first.

- separate frequently changing data from static data
- be ready to split data/databases
- think about how to invalidate cache/s

scaling <> language

Rewriting from one language to another isn't very hard. Focus on architecture. Later you can fight with Python/Jython/C++ to reduce 10% of  cpu usage because your 1 000 servers produce too much heat.

http://highscalability.com/ there is a lot of Python stories there. I don't know any big service which uses Jython but i think it can be treated as a java.

http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/4/18/6-ways-not-to-scale-that-will-make-you-hip-popular-and-loved.html

Comment: +1 Speed comes from getting the static content downloaded quickly.  It's all about Apache and Cache and how to manage those files.  The Python/Django/Database stuff is easy.  Apache (and mod_wsgi) already do everything required to parallelize this very nicely.

Comment: I found this interesting about scalability and speed.  Twitter loves Ruby and they are switching parts of their infrastructure to the JVM to get better throughput.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohHdZXnsNi8